# Delete rows in one table which exist in another MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (X and Y) with the column E-Mail (column names: EmailX in table x and EMailY in table y). I want to delete the row(s) in table X when the Email adress in table X is one of the Email adresses in table Y. To make it clearer - I have a table of all customers (with mail addresse) and I want to delete the specific blocked users which are stored/saved in another table (with E-Mail addresse).

I tried it already with this, but it´s not working...

```
DELETE FROM X WHERE X.EmailX = Y.EmailY;
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM X
    WHERE X.EmailX IN (SELECT Y.EmailY FROM Y);
```

In order to reference a table, the table needs to be included in a `FROM` clause somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete X from X join Y on X.EmailX = Y.EmailY;
```